# Parse string to create a list of element

Tags: c++, string, string-parsing

I have a string like this:

> "\r  color=\"red\" name=\"Jon\" \t\n depth=\"8.26\"   "

And I want to parse this string and create a `std::list` of this object:

```
class data
{
    std::string name;
    std::string value;
};
```

Where for example:

```
name = color
value = red
```

What is the fastest way? I can use boost.

### EDIT:

This is what i've tried:

```
vector<string> tokens;
split(tokens, str, is_any_of(" \t\f\v\n\r"));

if(tokens.size() > 1)
{
    list<data> attr;
    for_each(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), [&attr](const string& token)
        {
            if(token.empty() || !contains(token, "="))
                return;

            vector<string> tokens;
            split(tokens, token, is_any_of("="));
            erase_all(tokens[1], "\"");
            attr.push_back(data(tokens[0], tokens[1]));
        }
    );
}
```

But it does not work if there are spaces inside `" "`: like `color="red 1"`.

Comment: Fastest to write, fastest to compile, or fastest at runtime?

Comment: Fastest to gain self awareness?

Comment: I'm not inclined to write the actual code for a `homework` answer, but if it were me, I'd use [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/libs/xpressive/) or [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/).Qi.

Comment: Simply put, it entails work.  What have you tried?

Since you can use boost, use Boost.Tokenizer.  You may have to preprocess your input string to clean off the escape sequences though.

Comment: @ildjarn but what's the correct regex?

Comment: @Nick : Answering that would be writing the actual code for you. ;-]

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: @VivinPaliath I can but it does not work, and i think that there are better ways.

Comment: @Nick That's alright. We might be able to give you hints as to what you can change. Typically for questions it's helpful to show what you've done so far so we know that you've actually tried something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there will always be at least one white-space before the `name`, i think the following algorithm is fast enough:

```
list<data> l;
size_t fn, fv, lv = 0;

while((fv = str.find("\"", ++lv)) != string::npos &&
    (lv = str.find("\"", fv+1)) != string::npos)
{
    fn = str.find_last_of(" \t\n\v\f\r", fv);
    l.push_back(data(str.substr(++fn, fv-fn-2), str.substr(++fv, lv-fv)));
}
```

Where `str` is your `std::string` and `data` has a constructor of this type:

```
data(string name, string value)
    : name(name), value(value)
{   }
```

As you can see there was no need to use boost or regex, simply the standard library.

Comment: Pendantic, but as of C++11, regex is _part of_ the standard library. :-]

Answer (score 0):

**after your edit**:
you could do the following for the space problem:

(replace all spaces that are not within " " quotes with a \n)

```
void PrepareForTokanization(std::string &str)
{
    int quoteCount = 0;
    int strLen = str.length();
    for(int i=0; i<strLen; ++i){
        if (str[i] == '"' && (i==0 || (str[i-1] != '\\')))
            quoteCount++;
        if(str[i] == ' ' && quoteCount%2 == 0)
            str[i] = '\n';
    }
}
```

and before you call split, prepare the string, and then remove the space character from the split is_any_of

```
PrepareForTokanization(str);
split(tokens, str, is_any_of("\t\f\v\n\r"));
```